# Elegant way to assign header names to pandas dataframe when assigning new columns in for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a for loop that iteratively adds columns to a pandas dataframe. I wish to also name these new columns based on a list. I have a convoluted way now, is there a more elegant way to do this?

When assigning a new column, you have to specify a column name. However this cannot be variable for some reason. So I use a dummy and after change the column name based on a list I defined prior. This doesn't seem too elegant though.

The dataframe columns should be [wavelength, layers[0]_n, layers[0]_k, ... layers[*z*]_n, layers[*z*]_k]

```py
layers = ['Ag', 'SiO2', 'Au']    
colnames = ['wavelength']
for l in layers:
    colnames.append(l+'_n')
    colnames.append(l+'_k')

n = pd.read_csv('matdata\\' + layers[0] + '.csv')
n = n.iloc[:,0] #get only wavelength
for l in layers:
    data = pd.read_csv('matdata\\' + l + '.csv') #read appropriate file
    n = n.assign(a = data.iloc[:,1].values)
    n = n.assign(b = data.iloc[:,2].values)
    n.columns = colnames
```

Comment: You don't have to assign using `assign`, and if you assign in the 'simple' way there's no problem to use a variable: For example try x='a', followed by n[x]= data.iloc[:,1].values

Comment: if you want to create a new column, store values in a list and after the completion of `for` loop assign it to column. But you really need to use `for` loop? Look into `pandas` methods you'll find better alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I don't have access to your CSVs, etc, I am creating some fake data to simulate this process...

Let's start with several DataFrames:

```
n = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]], 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

dfb = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [7, 8, 9]])

layers = ['Ag', 'SiO2']

for layer in layers:
    n[layer] = dfb.iloc[:, 1].values
```

Yields:

```
   x  y  z  Ag  SiO2
0  1  2  3   2     2
1  4  5  6   5     5
2  7  8  9   8     8
```

Using this technique, rather than using `.assign()` allows for the use of a variable name to create the column header as each column is created.

Comment: This is indeed a lot more elegant, thank you! I didn't realize you could enter something to an index of the dataframe that doesn't exist yet. Very handy!